# Which is better for testing for non finite floats IsNaN or IsInf?

Tags: go, nan

I need to test for non finite floats and eliminate them. I was planing to use  `math.IsInf()`  to test the floats but I have seen some ppl using  `math.IsNaN()`  for this purpose. Is one of these better for this purpose than the other ? and if so why?

edit: This has been put on hold because it is unclear so here is more information that will hopefully clarify the question. I was doing exercise 3.1 from "The Go Programming Language" which references this [program](https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch3/surface/main.go). The exercise it asks

> If the function f returns a non-finite float64 value, the SVG file will   > contain invalid  elements (although many SVG renderers handle   > this gracefully). Modify the program to skip invalid polygons.

I was planing to solve it by adding the following to the corner func

```
if math.IsInf(z, 0) {
    return math.NaN(), math.NaN()
}
```

and changing the contents of the second for loop in main to

```
ax, ay := corner(i+1, j)
if math.IsNaN(ax) {
    continue
}
bx, by := corner(i, j)
if math.IsNaN(bx) {
    continue
}
cx, cy := corner(i, j+1)
if math.IsNaN(cx) {
    continue
}
dx, dy := corner(i+1, j+1)
if math.IsNaN(dx) {
    continue
}
fmt.Printf("<polygon points='%g,%g %g,%g %g,%g %g,%g'/>\n",
           ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy)
```

I wanted to check my work so I decided to look up any answers other ppl had posted online to this problem. No one else that I found had used  `math.IsInf()`  in there solutions but most had used  `math.IsNaN()` . This made me wonder if I was missing some something and if  `math.IsNaN()`  was better for this purpose for some reason. So I looked through the Go Docs for both functions. I looked up NaN on wikipedia and the IEEE 754. I did general web searches for why everyone else was using  `math.IsNaN()`  even though it seemed less intuitive to me. Then I did searches on here and on stackoverflow for answers after all of that I didn't really have an answer so I decided to post a question.

Comment: Do you know what floating-point infinity and NaN are?

Comment: @user2347112 - As I understand it NaN means Not a Number and represents responses to things like 0/0, a number to a negative power or an infinity. Infinity is any number to long to be represented by float. at least this is what my research has lead me to believe so far.

Comment: IsInf tests for positive or negative infinity. IsNaN tests for NaN. If you need one or both of those tests, use the function or functions that do what you need.

Comment: I found  this question, while doing the same exercise for "The Go Programming Langauge" book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need to account for either infinities, then `math.IsInf()` should suffice. However, if you need to guard against both infinities and values that are not numbers, you should use both in conjunction.

For more reading on floats: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

An example of `math.IsNaN()` not working for infinite values: https://play.golang.org/p/blHjr8i7p9

Answer (score -3):

Mathematically speaking, it's weird that NaN is a thing in programming because invalid expressions should not compile (unfortunately they do however).

Use `math.IsNaN()` if your number won't fit on the real line (like sqrt(-1), for example) or if it's mathematically undefined (like 0/0).

Use `math.IsInf()` if your number might be really large (in either the positive or negative direction) such that you don't have enough bits to represent it, or if it actually should be infinity.

Comment: Expressions can be valid but still produce senseless results (e.g.:  divide-by-zero).  How do you propose to resolve this weirdness without evaluating the whole program?  This is just the halting problem in disguise:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: Thanks for downvoting, but division by zero is also an invalid expression that should not compile (or at least produce a runtime error, e.g. NaN)... Are you familiar with mathematical limits? Anyway, smarter programming languages are on the horizon (but unlikely to see mainstream adoption anytime soon). You'll want to google dependent types and/or total functional programming.

Comment: the downvote isn't from me :)  I understand mathematical limits just fine -- do you understand why compile-time analysis cannot do what you would like it to do?  Do you understand how this is just the halting problem in disguise?  Simple example:  `1 / randint(0, 10)`.  Should this compile?  How about this example:  `1 / int(user_input("enter a digit"))`?  Your choices are (a) refuse to compile because you *might* get a `0` or (b) produce a `NaN` if you get a `0` value at runtime.

Comment: Since you seem interested in the halting problem, you'll probably enjoy reading about _total functional programming_ and its distinction between data and codata! Anyway, you'll find that many languages are slowly moving towards actually not just letting `1 / int(user_input("enter a digit"))` through a compiler without at least some form of explicit error handling (Maybe monads are even common in js these days!).

Comment: And my whole point is just that NaN is a poor way of handling runtime exceptions, and it primarily lingers on due to legacy.